# Bra Ket notation using only basic packages

Tags: amsmath, braket

I am setting questions onto my university's version of Moodle. This accepts LaTeX commands so I can write most maths into a question, however I can only use the preinstalled packages which does not include the `braket` package, but does include `amsmath` etc (there isn't exactly a list anywhere).

So is there a way I can write kets when the `\ket{}` command does not work?

Using the greater than symbol is not really ideal.

Comment: What symbol do you want? Like `\lvert \rangle`? If yes, you can define `\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle}` on preamble and simply use as `\ket{}`.

Comment: Please tell us whether the `amssymb` and `mathtools` packages are available.

Comment: @Mico, does `amsmath` load them?

Comment: The actual code in `braket.sty`, i.e. after removing the comments, is actually very short. You could just put it in the preamble of your document sandwiched between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. This is so much more powerful since the middle vertical lines also adjust their sizes.

Comment: @Sigur - Short answer: No. Longer answer: `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, and `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`.

Comment: @Mico, I'll never memorize which one loads others.

Comment: It might be an idea to figure out how Moodle actually renders math. Is it rendered as images or more like mathjax or katex? This will greatly affect any answer we can provide.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to put the command at the top of the document body, instead of the preamble.

You want the option to specify the size manually, since a bra and its matching ket should always be the same size.  If your preamble includes `mathtools`, you have an easy way to create new paired delimiters.  Otherwise, here's something quick and dirty:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\bra[2][]{#1\langle {#2} #1\rvert}
\newcommand\ket[2][]{#1\lvert {#2} #1\rangle}

\begin{align*}
  \bra{x}                   &\; \ket{y} \\
  \bra[\Big]{x^{c^k}_{a_b}} &\; \ket[\Big]{y}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Bra-ket sample]

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1\rvert} % Bra
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert#1\rangle} % Ket
\newcommand{\qprod}[2]{ \langle #1 | #2 \rangle} %Inner Product
\newcommand{\braopket}[3]{\langle #1 | #2 | #3\rangle} % Matrix Element
\newcommand{\expect}[1]{ \langle #1 \rangle} % Expectation value

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \bra{\psi}\\
        \ket{\phi}\\
        \qprod{\psi}{\phi}\\
        \braopket{\psi}{A}{\phi}\\
        \expect{A}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AMSmath is not suited for physics writing. You can use physics package: [Physics](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf). This is suitable for physics content and offers much more than bra-ket typing

Comment: There are many on the site who does not recommend the physics package as it makes a lot of questionable choices and unintuitive syntaxes. So knowing who to build your tools properly is a better choice